# Creating BezierPath from Texture in SpriteKit/Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit, uibezierpath, cgpath

So, basically, I have a sprite (.png) in `SpriteKit`, where most of the pixels are zero/no detail etc.

I wish to create a `UIBezierPath` of only the detail inside the Sprite, so later I can use `containsPoint`.

After a bunch of googling I found you can create a `PhysicsBody` using the path of the Texture in the sprite image, like this:

```
    let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "myImage.png")
    img.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: texture, size: img.size)
```

This creates a physics body around only the detail inside the image, excluding any alpha value pixels, if you know what I mean.

Is there a way to create a `BezierPath` doing the same? or maybe creating a `CGPath`, then using that to create a `BezierPath`?

The reason is, I'm hoping to test if a `CGPoint` is inside this sprite, without using the `physicsDelegate` or `physicsBodys`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you can pull the `img.physicsBody` path after creating the physics body?  I'm not sure that that will be a `BezierPath` though.

Comment: I thought that, because you can create a bezier from a CGPath but I'm not sure how to access the physics body path... So without some complex algorithm I don't think it's achievable easily

Comment: sorry to be a bother to you. Did you ever find a way to pull out the CGPath from a PhysicsBody?

Comment: No I didn't :( unfortunately.